# Two way conversion using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have my viewmodel classes and also my wcf service classes (separate project). I need to convert the viewmodel classes to wcf classes and also the other way around. Currently I am using the following method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static object To<T>(this object source)
    {
        // create the map
        Mapper.CreateMap(source.GetType(), typeof (T)); 

        // if the source is a list
        if(source is IEnumerable)
        {
            return Mapper.Map(source, source.GetType(), typeof (List<T>)); 
        }

        // return the mapping 
        return (T) Mapper.Map(source, source.GetType(), typeof (T)); 
    }

}

// converting the wcf class to viewmodel
var orders = (List<OrderStatusViewModel>) _orderStatusServiceClient.GetRecentOrders().To<OrderStatusViewModel>();
// converting the viewmodel to the wcf class 
var order = (Order) orderStatusViewModel.To<Order>();
```

Is this the best way to do this? Keep in mind I have to perform this in both the directions i.e viewmodel => wcf classes and wcf classes => viewmodel.

Comment: "Best way to do this" questions can be tricky to answer effectively. At a glance, I don't see a problem. **Is** this code causing a problem? What's the reason for your question?

Comment: It is not causing any problems! I was wondering if there is a better way. The problem might arise if the mapping between the two classes does not match due to different property names.

Comment: Mapper.DynamicMap<Destination>(source) should do that same thing. You could in fact do this : GetRecentOrders().Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<OrderStatusViewModel>) and drop the To extension method altogether.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be careful of is redefining your maps over and over again.  I've had code blow up from this.

Since your method is not tied to any specific types, I would recommend removing the CreateMap call and changing the Map calls to DynamicMap.

Also, if your generic parameter type is IEnumerable when your input is, then your if would be unnecessary with DynamicMap